# php json operation, count sub node, get sub nod

Tags: php, json

I have some json data like this, now I want count all the node "b" and if give number for them, how to get the specified node.

```
[
   {
      "a":[
         {
            "b":"aaa" //in case this is the first node "b", definition number 1
         },
         {
            "b":"bbb" //this is the second node "b", definition number 2
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "a":[
         {
            "b":"ccc" //this is the third node "b", definition number 3
         },
         {
            "b":"ddd" //this is the forth node "b", definition number 4
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "c":"eee"
   }，
]
```

Now in the example, there have 4 node "b", how to count them? and how to get the third node "b" in php code?

```
$json=json_decode($txt);
foreach($json as $data){
    if($data->a){
        foreach($data->a as $row){
            echo $row->b.'<br />';
                    //count($row->b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add a count var before iterating and inside the loops test every key for its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count them, you have to keep a counter, like this:

```
$counter = 0;
$json = json_decode($txt);
foreach ($json as $data) {
    if ($data->a) {
        foreach($data->a as $row){
            $counter++;
            if ($counter == 3) {
                echo 'Third "b": ' . $row->b . '<br />';
            }
        }
    }
} 
echo 'Number of "b"s: ' . $counter . '<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your code, you can done it with isset operator:

```
$json=json_decode($txt);
$count = 0;
foreach($json as $data){
if($data->a){
    foreach($data->a as $row){
        if (isset($row->b))
            ++$count;
        }
    }
}
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $json = json_decode($txt); echo count($json, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
```